# Obtener entidad y no array al hacer select en Doctrine con Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine2, symfony4

Estoy obteniendo un usuario desde la DB con la siguiente consulta en mi repositorio de usuarios:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('
         u.id,
         u.nombreUsuario
    ')
    ->where('u.id = :idUsuario')
    ->setParameter('idUsuario', $idUsuario)
    ->getQuery()
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

El problema es que al filtrar los campos no devuelve una entidad sino un array asociativo (`['id' => 1, 'nombreUsuario' => 'Genarito']`). Lo que yo necesitaría sería una entidad `Usuario` con los atributos correspondientes cargados. Ya probé con cambiar la última línea por:

```
...
->getOneOrNullResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT)
```

Pero tampoco funcionó, por lo que tuve que ponerme a codificar yo mismo el uso de los setters para asignar los campos que extraje de la base de datos para los atributos correspondientes.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo automáticamente a través de los repositorios?

Answer (score 0):

Puede hacer uso de los metodos `findOneById()`

```
 $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
 $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('idUsuario'=>$idUsuario))
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! El problema con esta solución es que me trae todos los campos. Yo necesitaría unicamente esos dos (`id` y `nombreUsuario`). Otra forma mas simple de lo que propones es `$repository->find($idUsuario)` pero cae en el mismo problema: trae todos los campos.

Comment: Entonces tedrias que tener un metodo que te retorne ambos campos, pero igual si instancias la clase traeras todos sus campos, o creas una clase con ambos campos y sus metodos get

Comment: Claro, quizás me expresé mal. Pero no es que no quiero que los campos "desaparezcan" sino que queden en NULL excepto por aquellos que están incluidos en el select. Como dijiste, tuve que implementar una función que cargue los campos a mano

Comment: Esperaré a ver si alguien conoce un método que resuelva este problema automáticamente

Answer (score 0):

Como dice trae la entidad $usuario = $repository->find($idUsuario) y luego accede a los campos que quieras mediante los getters eje: $usuario->getId() entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es poner null en los demás campos, entonces cambia el valor mediante los setters de la entidad eje: $usuario->setNombreUsuario(null)

Comment: Gracias por responder! :D Lo que dices es correcto, el tema es que quería evitar el uso de los setters y hacerlo con Doctrine automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer].